# Are fast candlestick charts possible in Python

Tags: python, pyqt

I tried drawing a few thousand candles in matplotlib.
When scrolling the chart slows down(hangs).

Eyllanesc helped me to realize the candlestick graph in pyqt.
The graph is beautiful and works faster than matplotlib.

But, all the same the chart slows down when scrolling. I changed the code a little. The file data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1trfarfC54SeO41XN5SChJogqLwTHO6ku/view).

Are relatively fast candlestick charts possible in Python, with a large amount of data?

The fact that I have a project in C# in it tens of thousands of candles and scrolled it much faster.

The data for drawing me offline. And I really need a lot of candles.
Maybe there's a function to make the graph more quickly?
(I'm not criticizing anyone, I just want to sort this out.)

Here's how the C# chart works, with over 40,000 candles. I attach GIF animation.

[C#](https://gifyu.com/image/hnUF)

[Python](https://gifyu.com/image/hnU0)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                         index_col='DATE',
                         parse_dates=True,
                         infer_datetime_format=True)


o = df.iloc[:, 0].values
h = df.iloc[:, 1].values
l = df.iloc[:, 2].values
z = df.iloc[:, 3].values

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.step = 0.1
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            sliderMoved=self.onAxisSliderMoved,
            pageStep=self.step * 100,
        )
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, sliderMoved=self.onZoomSliderMoved
        )

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        for w in (self._chart_view, self.scrollbar, self.slider):
            lay.addWidget(w)

        self.resize(640, 480)

        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()

        self._candlestick_serie = QtChart.QCandlestickSeries()


        tm = []

        for i in range(0, len(z)):
            o_ = o[i]
            h_ = h[i]
            l_ = l[i]
            c_ = z[i]
            self._candlestick_serie.append(QtChart.QCandlestickSet(o_, h_, l_, c_))
            tm.append(str(i))
        min_x, max_x = 0, i

        self._chart.addSeries(self._candlestick_serie)
        self._chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self._chart.legend().hide()
        # self._chart.setAnimationOptions(QtChart.QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setCategories(tm)
        self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setVisible(False)

        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)
        self.adjust_axes(100, 200)
        self.lims = np.array([min_x, max_x])

        self.onAxisSliderMoved(self.scrollbar.value())

    def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
        self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setRange(
            str(value_min), str(value_max)
        )

        if value_min > 0 and value_max > 0 and value_max < 10000:
            ymin = np.amin(l[int(value_min): int(value_max)])
            ymax = np.amax(h[int(value_min): int(value_max)])
            self._chart.axisY(self._candlestick_serie).setRange(ymin, ymax)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onAxisSliderMoved(self, value):
        r = value / ((1 + self.step) * 100)
        l1 = self.lims[0] + r * np.diff(self.lims)
        l2 = l1 + np.diff(self.lims) * self.step
        self.adjust_axes(math.floor(l1), math.ceil(l2))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onZoomSliderMoved(self, value):
        self.step=value/100
        self.onAxisSliderMoved(self.scrollbar.value())
        print(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Uploaded the file to Google drive, link updated

Comment: I see that it works correctly, I don't see any delay and that my PC has very few resources.

Comment: Added gifs, how graphics work in C# and Python.

Comment: try with: `self._candlestick_serie.setUseOpenGL(True)`

Comment: Python is probably not designed to draw a large number of candles.
What can not be said about the line chart, everything turns out very quickly.

Comment: That problem is not python but Qt, probably that type of series is not optimized. Some time ago we asked for more love for Qt Charts but maybe for Qt 5.14 we will see improvements or have to wait for Qt6.

Comment: @eyllanesc according to docs, setUseOpenGL does not support candlestick charts. I do hope charts get more attention in the future, the current options are very limited and slow.

Comment: Try https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot, which was built expressly for this purpose and works smoothly for me with over 250,000 candles. Including panning and zooming as expected. Part of the secret is drawing less detail as the chart zooms out (eg no bodies). All PyQT based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [pyecharts](https://pyecharts.org/#/en-us/). This is based on the fantastic [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) library which uses web technology for rendering. I consider the performance of this library to be state-of-the-art in open-source charting solutions. Also it is well documented and pretty easy to work with. An interactive linechart with a million points renders smoothly on a current laptop. Did not test candlesticks, though.